# javascript server application closing after simple error

Tags: javascript, node.js, exit

how do devs run javascript node app if script is exiting after a error ?

my app  is exiting after some dumb error which can be skipped

is any solution to ignore errors and to not exit the script ?

i tried those but still no luck

`process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) { console.log('Caught exception: ' + err); process.stdin.resume(); });`

`process.on('UnhandledRejection', function (err) { console.log(' UnhandledRejection: ' + err); process.stdin.resume(); });`

Comment: You should probably handle the error, rather than trying to prevent the program from exiting. Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling#try...catch_statement

Comment: Interesting read: https://blog.heroku.com/best-practices-nodejs-errors